# Is there any way to preserve the actual function, even after wrapping up with a decorator in python?

Tags: python, function, decorator, wrapper

```
    @dec_sub
    def sub(a, b):
        c= a-b
        return c
    
    def dec_sub(func):
        def wrapper(a, b):
            if a<b:
                a, b = b, a
            return func(a, b)
        return wrapper
    
    print(sub(48, 9)) # first digit is bigger than the second one yields positive return
    print(sub(1, 8)) # second digit is bigger than the first one also yields positive return

#Output : 39
          7
```

In the above code, how to use the function 'sub' in a usual way without the influence of the decorator?

Comment: you want a<b true always ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use decorator syntax to create a decorated function.

```
def sub(a, b):
    c = a - b
    return c


wrapped_sub = dec_sub(sub)
```

Or, you can use `func_tools.wraps` to create an object that exposes a reference to the original function.

```
from functools import wraps


def dec_sub(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(a, b):
        if a<b:
            a, b = b, a
        return func(a, b)
    return wrapper

@dec_sub
def sub(a, b):
    c = a - b
    return c


sub(48, 9)   # the decorated function
sub.__wrapped__(48, 9)  # the original function
```

Comment: My  first clarification is 
1) Is the above answered used in the production environment? 
2) If so, why do they teach in some websites about decorators like I have asked in my post?

Comment: Decorator syntax is just a shortcut for the function application shown in the first example, except the result of the decorator is assigned back to the original name. If you really want names bound to both the original and the decorated versions, there's no reason not to use explicit function application as shown.